Unidirectional Lazy @OneToOne @MapsId on JPA
I have 2 entities User and Doctor, as you may guess, my idea is having a OneToOne relationship between them, my step to step is creating first a User, and after the User is activated, create a Doctor who will have as primary key, a foreign key of the activated User.
I´m searching for create a Doctor whitout including the Object User on the process since the User is already created.
Here´s the code:
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Authorities authority;
    private boolean active;
    private String activationKey;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Doctor {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private User user;
    private String name;
    private String address;
}

then, Create a User
{
    "id": "3",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "phone": "phone",
    "password": "password",
    "authority": "DOCTOR"
}


and after its activated, try to create a Doctor
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Third User",
    "address": "address",
    "newPassword": "newPassword"
}

but, results in error "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.example.demo.domain.Doctor.user]
I´ve been trying change loadtype of OneToOne, and also set null to user when saving it, but still doesn´t work.

At first add @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")  for user property,then instead of trying to set the Doctor's ID directly, retrieve the User entity first and then set it in the Doctor object before saving it.

Is it necessary to attach the user to each query of Doctor even though the User is already created? seems impractical
